# Visual Studio 2015, Create Panel crahses the IDEA every time

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am experiencing some technical difficulties regarding VS 2015 E.

**Problem** 
Opening VS 2015 E, and navigating to the "New Project" panel, the program immediatly freezes when I access this panel.

**Debugging**
This problem suddently started one day, it was right after I installed the "Visual Micro" extension(Seems like this was a coincidence). Now I have removed Resharper, Visual Micro and every other extension that I installed. This did not help, I have uninstalled, repaired, deleted VS, and removed the personal VS folder in "Documents", did not work.

When I navigate to "Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDEA" and open cmd to enter "devenv.exe/safemode" which disables all addons, then the problem is fixed. But I dont know which addon caused the problem.

It is so frustrating to not be able to create any projects, and I really need this to work for my assignments at school, is there anyway to completely remove VS 2015 and all it's addons and third party tools. Or better, is there a way to figure out what addon is causing the problem?

Comment: Use the [vendor's forum](http://www.visualmicro.com/forums/) to find help.

Comment: The Visual Micro extension was not the problem as I completely removed it from VS, their forum cant help me.

Comment: Go to tools->Extension and Updates. There will be an installed option in the left navigation menu. Take one package out at a time to find the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour that you describe seems very much to be due to the installation of a third-party extension.

Even when you uninstall a misbehaving plug-in, it can leave configuration files or it can have altered your environment just enough to cause Visual Studio to have an ongoing problem.

I would assume [Occam's razor is at play here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor): It's likely one of the plugins you name (potentially in concert with one another even) that is causing your trouble.

Open a developer command prompt and run Visual Studio from the command line with the /Log option ([see here for details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx)). The resulting log will usually give you some inclination of what is causing your problem.

Comment: Turns out that if I wait for some minutes the panel starts working again, so there are probably some other service running on the same thread requesting focus of the program. After the wait, I can open and close the IDEA successfully creating new projects. This is also the reason the log file did not have any errors in it. I have tried waiting before without luck, so it seems a bit random, the freeze will come and go, but for now, I am in the clear zone. Thx for the answer, I will post the ridiculously simple bug that caused this when I find it.